# Getting NullReferenceException IRepository.Insert Call DNN Evoq 8.2

Tags: c#-4.0, dotnetnuke, repository-pattern, dotnetnuke-7

I'm working on a custom module for our site. The process flow is as follows.

- Customer hits a specific page
- Page detects if customer is authenticated

  - No - forces login/register
  - Yes - Continues
- Verifies customer data
- Retrieves token and ttl from sister site
- Stores data in db table
- Redirects customer to sister site using token to login

I have the following class:

```
[TableName("AutoRegister_Data")]
[PrimaryKey("rId", AutoIncrement = true)]
[Scope("ModuleId")]
[Cacheable("AutoRegister_Data", CacheItemPriority.Normal, 20)]
public class RegisterData
{
    public int rId { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LastToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code to update the database

```
using (IDataContext db = DataContext.Instance())
{
    var repo = db.GetRepository<RegisterData>();
    var user = repo.Find($"WHERE UserID = {currentUser.UserID}");

    db.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        if (!user.Any())
        {
            repo.Insert(dataRecord);
            db.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            string query = string.Empty;
            if (token != null)
            {
                query = $"SET [LastUpdateDate] = \'{DateTime.Now}\', [LastToken] = \'{token}\' WHERE [UserID] = {currentUser.UserID}";
            }
            repo.Update(query);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        db.RollbackTransaction();
        Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, ex);
    }
}
```

The dataRecord is of the class RegisterData.

I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

If I take the update out of a transaction block the table gets updated with correct data but the error still occurs.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

~Scott

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is the error being thrown, on the INSERT statement? Is the repo NULL or the dataRecord null? Is USERID populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`The `Find` method takes an `id` of the object in the database, or call it better the primary key value of the table in the database. Replace Where clause as in the code below

```
var user = repo.Where(UserID == $"{currentUser.UserID}");
```